# Check Microsoft Access Form Values before Save

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have an Access Form - lets call it "Add Labor" (Access 2007) that saves data into a table.

The table has two columns in particular called "Start Date" and "End Date" (This table stores tasks)

There is also another table called FiscalYears which includes Start and End Dates for Fiscal Years, which is structured as follows

FyID
FYear
StartDate
EndDate

Example Data:

```
FYId FYear StartDate EndDate
-----------------------------
 1   2010   10/1/2009 9/30/2010
 2   2011   10/1/2010 9/30/2011
```

So in My Add Labor Form if someone enters labor that span across two fiscal years I need to enter two labor entries. Here is an example

If a user selects Labor Start Date = 6/30/2009
And End Date 10/2/2010 , it spans two fiscal years

So in my Labor Table I should enter two things

```
LaborID StartDate EndDate
-----------------------------
1        6/30/2009  9/30/2010
2        10/1/2010  10/2/2010
```

Basically I need to do a check before I save the record and add two records if they span Fiscal years, right now I'm just blindly doing Save Record on the form (inbuilt), but I guess I need to add some VBA. I've hardly ever used Access so this may be simple(hopefully). I am thinking instead of the event which just calls Save Record, I need it to add custom VBA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have an unbound form for adding the dates, you can say:

```
Dim rsFY As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsAL As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As Database
Dim sSQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb

''Select all years from the fiscal years table    
sSQL = "SELECT FYear, StartDate, EndDate " _
  & "FROM FiscalYears WHERE StartDate>=#" & Format(Me.StartDate, "yyyy/mm/dd") _
  & "# Or EndDate <=#" & Format(Me.Enddate, "yyyy/mm/dd") _
  & "# ORDER BY FYear"

Set rsFY = db.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
Set rsAL = db.OpenRecordset("AddLabor") ''table

''Populate recordset
rsFY.MoveLast
rsFY.MoveFirst

Do While Not rsFY.EOF

    ''Add records for each year selected
    rsAL.AddNew
    If rsFY.AbsolutePosition = 0 Then
        rsAL!StartDate = Format(Me.StartDate, "yyyy/mm/dd")
    Else
        rsAL!StartDate = rsFY!StartDate
    End If

    If rsFY.AbsolutePosition + 1 = rsFY.RecordCount Then
        rsAL!Enddate = Format(Me.Enddate, "yyyy/mm/dd")
    Else
        rsAL!Enddate = rsFY!Enddate
    End If

    rsAL.Update

    rsFY.MoveNext
Loop
```

If the code was running in a main form with a subform showing the Addlabor table, you could update the subform to show the new records like so:

```
 Me.Addlabor_subform.Requery
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a FiscalYears table?  If your organization's fiscal years always start on Oct. 1 and end on Sept. 30, you can use a function to determine the fiscal year for a given date.

```
Public Function Fy(ByVal pDate As Date) As Integer
    Dim intYear As Integer
    Dim intReturn As Integer
    intYear = Year(pDate)
    If pDate > DateSerial(intYear, 9, 30) Then
        intReturn = intYear + 1
    Else
        intReturn = intYear
    End If
    Fy = intReturn
End Function
```

And simple functions to return the Start and End dates for a given year.

```
Public Function FyStart(ByVal pYear As Integer) As Date
    FyStart = DateSerial(pYear - 1, 10, 1)
End Function

Public Function FyEnd(ByVal pYear As Integer) As Date
    FyEnd = DateSerial(pYear, 9, 30)
End Function
```

You can then determine how many fiscal years are included in a given date range by:

```
Fy(EndDate) - Fy(StartDate)
```

But I may be totally off base because you said "Start Date = 6/30/2009 And End Date 10/2/2010" spans two years.  However, this expression returns 2 (3 years):

```
Fy(#10/2/2010#) - Fy(#6/30/2009#)
```

Comment: I can see doing it the way it's described because you may want to allocate part of the expense to the first FY and and part to the second. That can be done in SQL, of course, but it's a lot easier to do it with records in a table. It seems to me that what he's doing is more of a "distribution" table, i.e., taking a period of labor and create records to break down distribution of costs to the relevant fiscal years. That's typically pretty important for accounting purposes.

Comment: @David I wonder if we're talking about 2 different things.  The point I tried to make is he may be able to split a period of labor into separate FY records without using a FiscalYears table.